# How to change kernel boot options in GRUB 2

Tags: grub2

In old GRUB, if I wanted to change boot options, I would use a line starting with the word `kernel` in "**/boot/grub/menu.lst**":

```
kernel /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1 ro MY BOOT OPTIONS
```

Now since I'm using GRUB 2, I looked under "**/etc/grub.d/10_Linux**" for something similar, but I'm not even sure that's the right place to do this.

Comment: If it matters, I use Debian.

Comment: Funny, I remember upvoting this question before...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and set your parameter in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. For example I have:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="dolvm"
```

I learned this from [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#/etc/default/grub%20%28file%29). Other sources are either too hard to find, or I didn't dig deep enough.