# How do I apply parameters to specific kernels with GRUB 2?

Tags: linux-kernel, grub2

I have several kernels in `/boot`. One of them, `linux-cc`, is for heavy computation, i.e., 100Hz, no preemption, no graphics. I've created a `systemd` target, named `compute.target`, that only brings the system up and then starts an `ssh` server. I'm using GRUB2, and I'd like to add the `systemd.unit=compute` parameter **only** to the mentioned kernel.

I've read [How do I add xen kernel boot parameters in grub2?](https://serverfault.com/questions/299877/how-do-i-add-xen-kernel-boot-parameters-in-grub2), but it does not apply to my situation (I've tried adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_CC="systemd.unit=compute`" to `/etc/default/grub`, but it didn't work).

Does anyone know how to do this? I'm using ArchLinux, and I would like to keep using `grub-mkconfig` if it is possible.

P.S.: Maybe I could add this parameter as a hard-coded kernel option, but it does not seem very flexible.

Comment: Note this isn't a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7959/how-to-change-kernel-boot-options-in-grub-2?rq=1 as that is the same as the question linked above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find if you maintain multiple kernels with different options its easier to roll your own `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` rather than use `grub2-mkconfig`.

An example entry is:

```
menuentry 'Linux 3.10.17 (sde) kernel-3.10.17-g' {
    root=hd0,1
    linux /boot/kernel-3.10.17-g domdadm dolvm root=/dev/md3
    initrd /boot/initrd-3.10.17-g
}
```

Where everything after the name of your kernel on the `linux` line are the boot options you want to pass to that specific kernel.  Obviously, your setup will differ than mine, but this is demonstrate that manual setup of grub2 really isnt much different than grub.

If you want to combine this method with the "grub2 way", you can put custom entries into `/etc/grub.d/XX_custom` or the equivalent setup on your distro and the `grub2-mkconfig` script will pull them into the generated configuration file.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I have ended up doing. The problem is that the file might get overriden in the future with upgrades, but, well, it's just `systemd.unit=compute.target`.

Comment: @Kalrish I doubt so. `99_custom` doesn't get modified at upgrade of any grub package (at least not debian's).

Comment: @Braiam - oh, but, the kernel image is being autodetected by **grub-mkconfig**. If I added a custom entry in `99_custom`, as you suggest, wouldn't it be later duplicated? (Thanks.)

Comment: Yes, but is a lesser evil, no? just name the entry with something the GRUB will not come up with and you will be fine ;).

Comment: @Braiam Ok! I'll try it. See you in the next boot, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

## The Unofficial Hack Method

When GRUB 2 came out it was different in that `grub.conf` was no longer supposed to be edited by the user; the distro package manager would do whatever and then there was supposed to be a means for the user to make changes using some kind of tool that was not documented at that time (I'm sure they have lots of nice docs for it now, of course ;|).

I believe part of the goal was to simplify things by adding a layer of abstraction.  I'm not so sure how well that worked out, and (full disclosure) I've  never bothered to do things the grub 2 "right way". The the "wrong" way is just too easy, and it will work for you here:

Despite the warning at the top of the file, you can edit it.  The distro installer will modify it when the kernel is updated and will leave your entries alone (at least, on Fedora, Ubuntu, and I am pretty sure Debian), although it may add one to the top and make it default, so when that happens, you'll have to move some entries around or change the index in `set default`.  It may also happen that if the installer finds the file changed it won't add any new entries (Fedora), so watch for that if you want access to the updated distro kernels in the grub menu.

It is easy to tell by looking at the file (`/boot/grub2/grub.conf`) how it is structured in relation to the grub menu you see at boot.  Every `menuentry` block  has a line like this somewhere:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.11 root=/dev/sda1 resume=/dev/sda3 fbcon=scrollback:512k
```

It will probably have `root=UUID=...` and not device nodes.  If you are not using an initramfs it will be the last line, otherwise it will be followed by an `initrd` line.

Anyway, that is the kernel command line; `/boot/vmlinuz-3.11` is the path to the kernel on the root filesystem and everything after that are parameters passed to the kernel.